# How to set FeeCalculator value to use BaseFee or FixedGasPrice in pallet_evm config?

Tags: parachain, frontier

I was trying to add Frontier into my parachain as a dependency...
then I got this error

```
     Compiling parachain-template-runtime v0.1.0 (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/runtime)
  error[E0412]: cannot find type `BaseFee` in this scope
     --> /mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/runtime/src/lib.rs:415:23
      |
  415 |     type FeeCalculator = BaseFee;
      |                          ^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

But I don't know how to import this `BaseFee` because I could not find where it was imported from in the Frontier repository's template/runtime/src/lib.rs:
https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/polkadot-v0.9.25/template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L330

```
impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
    type FeeCalculator = BaseFee;//from Frontier template, where is this declared?
    //type FeeCalculator = FixedGasPrice;//from moombeam;
    //type FeeCalculator = ();//From JoshOrndorff
...
}
```

or should I use the `FixedGasPrice` from Moombeam?

```
pub struct FixedGasPrice;
impl FeeCalculator for FixedGasPrice {
    fn min_gas_price() -> (U256, Weight) {
        (
            (1 * currency::GIGAWEI * currency::SUPPLY_FACTOR).into(),
            1u64,
        )
}
```

What is the difference? It seems I can use `FixedGasPrice` to set the minimum gasPrice...

so that the user must pay `1 * currency::GIGAWEI * currency::SUPPLY_FACTOR` for every `1u64` amount of Weight. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `pallet_base_fee` in the `construct_runtime!` somehow imports this `BaseFee` variable:

```
construct_runtime!(
    ...
    {
    BaseFee: pallet_base_fee,
}
```